# More efficient way to code this in matlab

Tags: matlab, physics

So I am working on [this paper](http://www.mcgrating.com/references/ref02.pdf).  I am currently trying to code the Matrix given after equation 20.

I have the following codes:

```
cx = 1/(1+aprime^2);
cp = 1/period * int(cx*exp(-i*m*K*x),x,0,period);

d_x = aprime/(1+aprime^2);
dp = 1/period * int(d_x*exp(-i*m*K*x),x,0,period);
alpham = (k * sinteta) + m*K;
betam = sqrt((2*pi/lbd)^2 - subs(alpham,m)^2);
beta0 = subs(betam,0);
alpha0 = subs(alpham,0);


for p = -Mmax:Mmax;
    for r = -Mmax:Mmax;

        A((p+Mmax)+1,(r+Mmax)+1,j) = subs(alpham,r)*subs(dp,m,(p-r));

        B(p+Mmax+1,r+Mmax+1,j) = subs(cp,m,p-r);

        C(p+Mmax+1,r+Mmax+1,j) = -subs(alpham,p)*subs(alpham,r)*subs(cp,m,p-r)  +  k^2 * n(j)^2 *kronDel(p,r);

        D(p+Mmax+1,r+Mmax+1,j) = subs(alpham,p)*subs(dp,m,p-r);

    end
end
T(:,:,j) = [A(:,:,j) , B(:,:,j)
    C(:,:,j) , D(:,:,j)];
```

The j's are insignificant because I have to do it for 3 different medium.  But I was wondering if there was any clear mistakes, because either i)it takes forever based on 'aprime' or ii)I end up with NaN in the matrix, which does not allow me to take `eig`

Currently aprime is `diff(abs(x-.5),x)`

thansk for any help!

Comment: you are using symbolic substitution which will inevitably be a bit slower, can you change it so you are not doing that

Comment: I am not sure.  I am trying to think how I could do that instead...

Comment: Can you abandon the symbolic stuff and use numerical quadrature integration instead, e.g., [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) (or [`quadgk`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadgk.html) if you're using an older version of Matlab)? Or, solve those integrals once and write them out as regular vectorized floating-point equations in terms of their parameters.

Comment: Yes but then the problem is finding writing the function `cx` because it involves `aprime` and I do not know how to make a 'derivative' vector